# Stepper Next button text - Name of next step vs. simply "Next"

Tags: buttons, back-button, next

I have a multi-step form with five steps.

At the bottom of each page there is a button to go to the previous step and the next step.

Should the text inside the button have the name of the next / previous step? Or should they say Previous / Next?

Steps are shown to the user at the top of the form and are clickable:

```
1. Recipient     2. Options     3. Access     4. Contact
```

Let's say we are on step 2, should the buttons say

```
[ < Recipient ]                  [ Access > ]
```

or should they simply be

```
[ < Previous ]                   [ Next > ]
```

Note that the buttons have arrows to let the user know that he is going back (<) or forth (>) using horizontal MUI stepper.

Comment: Here are some thoughts on 'Next' vs. 'Continue', maybe helpful: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53921/next-vs-continue

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several options.

1. Use [previous topic] and [next topic]. Pros: it's probably clear what the buttons do, especially with the addition of the arrows.
2. Use "previous" and "next". Cons: user might think it will refresh the page and delete/invalidate entries. Perhaps you could indicate the state of the pages in the top contents row.
3. Merge all pages into a long vertically scrolling page. You can use a fixed navigation bar to highlight the current position/category. Pros: keep everything on one page. Cons: long scrolled page; later pages may require entries from earlier pages; won't win any design awards.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a design decision. The only problem I see is that by using the standard <kbd>previous</kbd> / <kbd>next</kbd> labels, the user knows for sure that it's a stepper and consequently they stay on the same page.

If one of these buttons has a different label with an <kbd>XXXXX</kbd> name it can lead to the confusion that it's a button to jump to another page.

There is another solution for desktop by adding a tooltip to each button with the destination name:

[image]